# no se visualiza script en android

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, web, app

Hola gente como están mi problema es el siguiente yo tengo una transmisión que realizo mediante un script en mi web pero al momento de visualizar la pagina en un dispositivo móvil, dicha transmisión no se visualiza y no se si necesito configurar un script diferente ya que quiero pasarla a una app movil para transmitir por dispositivos móviles.

este es el script que estoy utilizando:

```js
<script type='text/javascript'> width=720, height=480, channel='tvCNC', g='1';</script><script type='text/javascript' src='//www.liveflashplayer.org/resources/scripts/hliveFlashEmbed.js'></script>
```

Comment: Hola Victor, acostumbra agregar el código que estas usando para que te puedan brindar respuestas más acertadas.

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente debes asegurar que tu `WebView` pueda ejecutar javascript, esto mediante el método `setJavaScriptEnabled()`:

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

En cuanto a tu script puedo notar que no tiene definido el protocolo http:// , esto es necesario, puedes ver como ejemplo el código embebido de mi canal:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> width=720, height=480, channel='Jorgesys', g='1';</script><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.liveflashplayer.org/resources/scripts/hliveFlashEmbed.js'></script>
```