# Insertar script en una app android

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, script, app

Hola gente como están tengo una consulta tengo un script que es un reproductor que tiene una transmisión en vivo 24h mi duda es si este script puedo pasarlo a una app ya que lo e intentado pero conozco poco de desarrollo de app

```html
<script type='text/javascript'> width=720, height=480, channel='tvCNC', g='1';</script><script type='text/javascript' src='//www.liveflashplayer.org/resources/scripts/hliveFlashEmbed.js'></script>
```

Comment: Deberías echarle un ojo al WebView de Android, te permitirá introducir páginas web y código Javascript dentro de un contenedor web de tu app de Android https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda pero ya lo probé y no  se ejecuta el script incluso activando el javascript webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: Ya realizaste una pregunta similar, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164663/no-se-visualiza-script-en-android lo importante aquí es verificar si tu transmisión en verdad funciona, por el momento no esta funcionando. Primero asegura que el video definido por el canal en verdad se muestre, esto ya no es problema de Android.

Comment: la transmisión esta en vivo la puedes ver en la pagina http://canalcnc.com.co